# how to mix procedural textures for a natural waves of sand displacement effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I want to achieve a nice wave procedural texture in order to get a realistic sand displacement effect. here is my current set up

[image]

but I want to waves mix more randomly in order to give brunchy like look as shown below

[image]

I made two slightly different located wave texture and tried to mix them with a suitable mixRGB node, however I couldn't manage to find a correct solution, all I cannot get a good result but only like below

[image]

EDIT: I have played around a little bit more with the mixing option, I still couldn't figure out branching though

[image]

(thanks to for the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDuArvDdRu4) which made me started work on it )

Comment: Maybe use an RGB curves node to get the pointy peaks.

Comment: To be a little bit more clear, where abouts you mean should it be added to?

Comment: Between the wave texture and the multiply node in the first image.  I am trying to get that bunchy look you are talking about, it's harder than I originally thought it would be.

Comment: Thank you, i tried many things but could figure out, perhaps another texture to plug in to fac at the mix node, but dont know yet, hope you can discover a way

Answer (score 6):

You can distort a texture using another texture, like this:

[image]

(click on the images to enlarge)

Or you could mix bumps and displacement with other textures:

[image]

If what you are after fake relief (or bumps maps), but not real geometry displacement, this would work fine. Otherwise I would recommend using a displace modifier.

Comment: thanks for this answer as well, I'm gonna study all carefully, and show the result asap