# What is the most effective way to use displacement with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

I have a PBR material with a normal map for some surface defects. I'm trying to use Displace to emboss some fonts but I'm just getting an outline instead of full depth.

Reference image:

[image: Ref Image]

Node set up:

[image: Node Set Up]

Texture: (this is cropped the original is 2048x2048) Also, I've tried many combinations black on white/middle grey/alpha etc.

[image: Texture]

Mesh:

[image: Mesh]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you show your source texture?

Comment: Yes, I had it ready to go and forgot... Thanks!

Comment: Are you using experimental Microdisplacement?

Comment: No, I read threads on it here and decided not to. But I am open to anything.

Comment: Switch on the "**experimental**" feature set, then in the material settings, change the displacement from "bump" to "**true**" or "both". https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45873/blender-cycles-true-displacement. Alternatively you can use the displace modifier, which will give you more nuanced control.

Comment: @cegaton - I have switched on "Experimental" but there isn't any displacement options showing up in the "Object Data". I'm using 2.78

Comment: The reason for the outline could be using normal map and displacement map in the same material if addressing this problem. It should be possible including that either in height map or in normal map instead.

Comment: @Mr Zak - My gut was telling me that might be the reason. Using a Normal Map (As suggested by Crantisz) yields a better result but I think it can be even better. I'll try a height map... I'm still trying to figure out "Experimental" as I cant find any displacement options when I enable it.

Comment: As to displacement in addition to already mentioned link read this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work. Generally this feature is used the same as displacement texture in your setup (*Both* method only worked for me but maybe it's not important)

Answer (score 2):

Add a glow effect in 2D editor like Gimp or Photoshop:

[image]

Next, create normal map using this image (in GIMP - [normal map plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/69))

[image]

Normal map gives mach better result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how does this solve my problem of the outline result that I am getting?

Comment: You have outlines because edges is to hard, I think. Add softness and use normal map instead of displacment