# What options do I have to make metal engravings and etchings in blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I'm want to create the hidden blade from assassin's creed brotherhood (video game)

I created the model and stuck on how to create engravings on the hand guard of hidden blade

Here are some reference pictures
[image]
[image]

The engravings on the blade doesn't has that much of a bump to them, so I'm going to add them in textures

But ones on the hand guard does

So my question what options do I have to make them?

I want it to be details just like in the first picture

So I don't think a texture with a bump map will do

PS: Still a noob in blender so... sorry if this question is stupid

Comment: if you need correct silhouette and shadows from lights, you need true displacement when using textures (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45874/7777), or you need to model or sculpt the surface.

Comment: Thx for the response but do you know which one give the more realistic result
if both are very close I would rather not sculpt this because it's very detailed

Comment: Thx for the response but do you know which one give the more realistic result
if both are very close I would rather not sculpt this because it's very detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sculpting and baking the normal is the best way of doing these... another not so very recommended process is to take out its UV layout into image editing software and create a greyscale map of the design you need over it and then use it as a bump map on the mesh...

Comment: thx for your answer 
I was looking for an answer to get away from sculpting but I guess no choise here
a lot of work but still will give a great result